# What is the correct redirect URL for chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow?

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, dart, github-api, google-chrome-app

I'd like to use the [chrome.identity](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity.html) API in a chrome packaged app to allow the user to authenticate with [github](http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/).

From the app side, I'm happy with:

```
chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(
  {'url':'https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=clientidgoeshere','interactive':true}, 
  functionToTakeRedirectURL
);
```

But I'm unsure what the redirect URL should be on the github side. When the app is live, I'll set the redirect url to https://appidgoeshere.chromiumapp.org on the github application page, but I don't think that url is available until the app is live.

Does anybody know where to point the redirect when you're writing the app?

I'm writing the app in Dart using the [chrome.dart](https://github.com/dart-gde/chrome.dart) library, but I think the same problem exists if I was writing in plain javascript.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This [github auth chrome app sample](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/blob/master/samples/github-auth/index.js) uses `chrome.runtime.id` to build the redirect URL:

```
 var redirectUri = 'https://' + chrome.runtime.id +
                  '.chromiumapp.org/provider_cb';
```

References:

- [chrome.runtime](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html)
- [Sample app linked to from this (chrome app identity) page](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity.html)

Comment: Thank you sir, https://developer.chrome.com/docs/webstore/identify_user/  doesn't mention the final part 'provider_cb'

Answer (score 12):

You can use [chrome.identity.getRedirectURL](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity#method-getRedirectURL) so you don't have to hardcode the redirect URL pattern in your app.