# Chrome extension identity callback URL getting a DNS error

Tags: google-chrome-extension, dns, chromium

I am developing a chrome extension which requires authentication through a non-google service. It is currently set to unlisted in the Chrome Web Store
The expected flow is as follows:

1. User opens the extension
2. Extension check for an authentication code
3. If the code does not exist, use `launchWebAuthFlow` to start authentication with the service
4. User authenticates with the service
5. Service redirects to the extension with the authentication code
6. Code is extracted and the user is authenticated

Up to step 4 is working fine, but when redirecting back to the extension, I keep getting a DNS

> 'appId'.chromiumapp.org’s server DNS address could not be found.
>   Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
>   DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

`'appId'` is the ID for the chrome extension. My `manifest.json` contains the permission for the service url:

```
...
"permissions": [
    "*//<service-provider-url>/*"
]
...
```

The call to the auth flow looks like this:

```
chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({'url':'<URL for auth>', 'interactive' : true}, function(responseUrl){
    // stuff happens here
});
```

The callback url is registered with the provider and, as far as understand, is being called correctly to return the extension, according to the [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity#method-launchWebAuthFlow):

> This method enables auth flows with non-Google identity providers by
>   launching a web view and navigating it to the first URL in the
>   provider's auth flow. When the provider redirects to a URL matching
>   the pattern https://.chromiumapp.org/*, the window will close,
>   and the final redirect URL will be passed to the callback function.

Is there something I might be missing during set up?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: The reason that a [mcve] is required is that *we want to help*. It is **much** easier to help if we don't have to recreate any of the code needed to duplicate the problem. This is code that you already have. So, please help us to help you and provide a *complete* [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Without a [mcve], the amount of effort required to even begin to help you is **much** higher, which *significantly* reduces the number of people willing/able to help you. Even if we put out the extra effort, we have to **guess** at significant portions of what your problem might be.

Comment: Did you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18312118/what-is-the-correct-redirect-url-for-chrome-identity-launchwebauthflow

Comment: Can you make sure that the redirect is to https:// and not http:// ?